# Node JS Randomly stops executing - Shows no errors

Tags: node.js, command, line, execution

I am not sure where to start looking for the issue here.

I recently updated from angular 5 to angular 8. The application runs fine after the update. I don't know if this is related.

All of the sudden, my Node JS scripts stop seemingly at random. Sometimes they run, usually they don't. This is any script.
By "Stopping" I mean the console, mid execution, leaves the last line it wrote up, and on the next line, I am able to write more commands. 
Example:

```
 C:\location\> npm start
 ng serve --aot

 ** Angular Live development server is listening on .....*
 12 % building 22/23 modules 1 active ...somefile.ts

 C:\location\>
```

There is no error, even when I run --verbose. Also, if I have multiple windows up or multiple servers running, they all stop at the same time. It is happening regardless of the application or package, including http-server, Angular, and installing dependencies.

I couldn't find anything related online. Has anyone ever seen this?

Answer (score 0):

Update:
The issue is caused by my lack of CPU.

---

I thought I fixed it by updating, but that didn't work.

----------- (previous reply, not a solution)

<s>It appears some of my installed dependency versions conflicted with package.json. Basically something did not fully update as expected.</s>

I resolved the issue by running npm install.